Best (and cheapest) way to get 9V AC + 5V DC?
For a project, I need a power adapter able to output 9v AC and 5v DC.
Both will need around 9W each.
Where I live I can't find ready made ones and electronic shops in Egypt are kind of weird.
So I was thinking: for the 5v I could use a good USB charger.
And get a 12v power adapter and remove the rectifier.
Perhaps there are better choices.
Unfortunately I am not great with a soldering iron. So the easiest, the better.
Thanks in advance to whoever would help me.

Get two adapters?

Best and cheapest are rarely achieved at the same time. For what purpose this is, what are you powering? A Commodore 64?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What you suggested is OK but what is your real load?

If your 9  V DC needed to be more stable than mains, you're in trouble.

At the cost of an over capable transformer and possible issues with relationship of the AC and DC outputs you could use a 9VAC centre tapped transformer giving you 4.5VAC on one half which you bridge rectify. Peak DC is 4.5 x 1.414 - rectifier drop. Not much over 5V. Probably needs excessively heavy filtering. Better with Schottky diode rectfiers. || Better is a transforner with two windings for the two supplies.

Two from here  - or they may make you a custom one  https://microohm-eg.com/product-category/modules/power-supplies/transformer/?srsltid=AfmBOooTq_1UxpbabYZ1dx85SnMRjLNUpkjculvqjV_IFjxmfG8cq5KB

5V @ 9W is 1.8A, so you should be able use a good USB charger.
9V AC @ 9W is going to be a bit more difficult. You might be better to purchase a 240V:9V 50Hz transformer and put it in an enclosure with a fuse. Be sure to over-rate the 9V transformer if the load is not resistive-in other words you may need a 12VA transformer to deliver 9W into something like a rectifier/capacitor.

The best and cheapest solution is an oxymoron. You cannot have both. The best solution I can think of is a 240 VAC to 9 VAC 40 VA transformer. Use the raw output to supply your 9 VAC requirements. To obtain a 5-volt DC supply, rectify the 9 VAC, filter it with a capacitor, and then use one of the 5-volt regulators available on the market.

Which kind of 5V regulators? And what if the need is to have isolated 9VAC and 5VDC?

if you need isolation use a transformer with twin secondaries
